# Can Delphi XE Be Installed On Drive D

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I have a new pc with a SSD as drive C and I tried to install DelphiXE4 on Drive D which is a regular hard drive, but a lot of space on drive C has been used.   *.bpl, *.dcp, *.dcu and *.pas files are in c:\program data. Is there a way to reinstall or modify the Delphi XE4 installation to minimize the Delphi footprint on Drive C?

Comment: What files were installed to C? Where on that drive were the files installed?

Comment: I'm sure this has been covered before here. But I cannot find the question. This doesn't happen for my installations. How are you installing? From DVD image, or downloaded from web?

Comment: From ISO in Windows 8.

Comment: Confirmed for XE2 on Win7 64 bit: c:\program data\{2E13DE59... contains 2.3 GB of Delphi stuff, c:\users\all users\{2E13DE59... contains 2.3 GB of Delphi stuff (a junction or symbolic link?), c:\users\public documents\RAD studio\ contains 0.4 GB of Delphi stuff

Comment: Oh, it's in hidden folders. I feel sure you can just delete all of that.

Comment: An adventurous man would rename the folder and try to run delphi. A reckless man would just delete that installer-junk.

Comment: @JanDoggen "a junction or symbolic link?" Yes, a clean normal install of Windows (at least 7 and 8, perhaps Vista too) will let "C:\Users\All Users" redirect to "C:\ProgramData".

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Why not? I was able to...

Comment: @MasonWheeler It would not let me. Since I tried, I upvoted the answer there. Perhaps that was enough. Yes, I can now vote to close.